# What is wrong with this ruby code?

Tags: ruby

I get a "400 Bad Request" and "Did you forget the body variable?"
Code:

```
require "rest-client"
require "json"

# This is the ID that you copied down in the last exercise
your_folder_id = "816582409"

# Add the "body" variable here
body = { "description" => "I made this on Codecademy!"
} 

response = RestClient.put(
"https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/#{816582409}",
JSON.generate(body),
:authorization => "Bearer" << "AKGEp7MoDfLAKnMyxTt3nSNtohXW3bt1"
)

JSON.parse(response.body)["description"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The url of api call shouldn't be `https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/816582409` or `"https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/#{@your_folder_id}"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space between Bearer and nonsense. You have something like:

```
response = RestClient.put(
"https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/#{816582409}", 
JSON.generate(body),
:authorization => "Bearer " << "AKGEp7MoDfLAKnMyxTt3nSNtohXW3bt1"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`"https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/#{816582409}"` evaluates to `"https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/"`  due to string interpolation.  As ararog suggests, put the variable itself in: `#{@your_folder_id}` or the plain number, not `#{816582409}`